# How to check anything in array, appears as a substring in the title

Tags: java

I have got some predefined company names in my Array String

I am trying to check if  anything in array, appears as a substring in the  title

This is my program the title has got the word "INDIABULLS" but why i am getting no

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] myFirstStringArray = new String[] {
                "INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE LTD.",
                "INDIABULLS REAL ESTATE LTD.", };
        try {
            List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(myFirstStringArray);
            String title = "INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE Q2 NET UP 24% AT RS 555 CR";
            String[] titleWords = title.toUpperCase().split(" ");
            for (String word : titleWords) {
                if (wordList.contains(word)) {
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should read the javadoc of [`List#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) see also `String#contains`

Comment: if (wordList.contains(word))

wordList is a list of two strings. You need to split those individual strings up, and then merge them into one list of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code (I have tested it):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] myFirstStringArray = new String[] { "INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE LTD.", "INDIABULLS REAL ESTATE LTD.", };
        try {
            List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(myFirstStringArray);
            String title = "INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE Q2 NET UP 24% AT RS 555 CR";
            String[] titleWords = title.toUpperCase().split(" ");
            for (String word : titleWords) {
                boolean found = false;
                for (String list : wordList) {
                    if (list.contains(word)) {
                        System.out.println("Yes");
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No");
                    }
                }
                if(found) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop once First Yes is reached ??

Answer (score 2):

Thats because the array of strings will contain `["INDIABULLS","HOUSING",...]` while your wordList contains `["INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE LTD.","INDIABULLS REAL ESTATE LTD."]`

So when you check if the wordList contains string "INDIABULLS" it returns false, because it doesnt contain such a string.

Answer (score 2):

According to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))
`contains(Object o)`

> Returns `true` if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns `true` if and only if this list contains at least
>   one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

In your case, `word` is `INDIABULLS` whereas `wordList` contains

```
wordList    String[2]
           [0]  "INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE LTD."
           [1]  "INDIABULLS REAL ESTATE LTD."
```

Hence `contains()` returns `false`.

Split `wordList` into `string` array by space can be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting No is because in this line

```
if (wordList.contains(word))
```

you check if list contains word but you should check if wordList(0) contains word either wordList(1) contains word.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
wordList.contains(word)
```

You are checking to see if the full name of each company is in the title. For example `"INDIABULLS"` exists in the title and so does `"HOUSING"` but not the full company name `"INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE LTD."`

1. One solution would be to call `split(" ")` on each `String` in `wordList` and iterate over the resulting `String[]`
2. Or for a probably simpler solution with less splitting use this for loop:

   ```
   for (String titleWord : titleWords) {
       for (String word : wordList) {
           if (word.contains(titleWord)) {
               System.out.println("Yes");
               break;
           } else {
               System.out.println("No");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] myFirstStringArray = new String[] {
                "INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE LTD.",
                "INDIABULLS REAL ESTATE LTD.", };
        try {
            List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(myFirstStringArray);
            String title = "INDIABULLS HOUSING FINANCE LTD. Q2 NET UP 24% AT RS 555 CR";
            String[] titleWords = title.toUpperCase().split(" ");
            for (String check : stringList) {
                if (title.indexOf( check ) >= 0 ) {
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I've made the following changes:

- Fix the `title` string value to contain `LTD.`, otherwise there is no match
- Use `indexOf` to test for a substring

Comment: I cannot fix the title as these are headlines received from rss so i am just checking if anything is part of it .

Comment: It is just for demonstration purposes. If you need a match, and there is no `LTD.` in the titles you receive, then simply don't check for it (i.e., change the values in `myFirstStringArray` instead).